# Animated sticky heard doesn't animate smoothly when scrolling up

Tags: jquery, css

This sticky menu animates the title(logo) to the left and the navigation to the right. When you scroll down the animation is smooth but when you scroll up the navigation is a little jumpy, not as the title.

The animation is done with **CSS3**:

`transition: all 0.4s ease;`

**JQuery** is only use to add a class:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

I guess the issue is with the css but can't figure out what it is. **[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2a0oqLbb/)**. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Try taking font-size out of the equation and do transforms (scale) only, CSS is very good at that but less great with animations where it has to recalculate position and pixel flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS `transition` is applied to the header links *only* when their ancestor has a "sticky" class. So, when that class is removed, the transition is not applied.

Apply the transition to the `<a>` elements *without* the "sticky" class, like you have done with your `<h1>`.

Instead of this:

```css
nav ul li a { ... }

.sticky nav ul li a {  
  ...
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

Do this:

```css
nav ul li a {
  ...
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sticky nav ul li a { ... }
```

Demonstration below:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
  } else {
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/* NAV */

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #335C7D;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sticky h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  right: 20px;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
nav ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sticky nav ul li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <span class="logo">
    <h1>Sticky Header</h1>
  </span>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<!-- an image for demonstration purposes -->
<img src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/how-to-create-an-animated-sticky-header-with-css3-and-jquery/large-image.jpg" alt="Big Image" />
```

Comment: Damn you beat me to it!